# Why won't Laflat give me the "Lynel Safari" sidequest?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Zora's Domain there is a Zora named Laflat who offers the sidequest [Lynel Safari](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Lynel_Safari). The quest involves taking a photo of the Lynel on top of Polymous Mountain to earn a set of Zora Greaves.

However, after finishing the main Zora quest to defeat Divine Beast Vah Ruta, Lafrat won't give me her sidequest. Any time I talk to her, she simply says:

> [Oh! Hmm... I suppose it was wrong of me to ask this of you. My apologies. Please don't concern yourself with my troubles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diZG2.jpg)

I've tried resetting the game and reloading my save file, but she always responds the same way.

Why won't Laflat give me the Lynel Safari sidequest?

Comment: Long shot, but did you happen to kill the Lynel by any chance?

Comment: @Wondercricket Nope. I left as soon as I gathered the shock arrows.

Comment: I figured that was the case. I read on [gamefaqs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75087111) that one possible reason was the Lynel was killed and needed to wait for a blood moon, so I thought I'd ask. It's weird how it is not letting you complete the quest, I was able to start it with no trouble

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to progress further on the main quest to get access to the Camera Rune.

After finishing the Great Plateau, you should've gotten a quest to go visit Impa called *[Seek Out Impa](https://www.thonky.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild/seek-out-impa)*. Complete that quest, and do what Impa tells you to do there.

Impa will then give you a quest to go seek out Purah in Hateno Village called *Locked Mementos*. After meeting Purah, she will give you a task to go retrieve a blue flame. Complete this and she will give you the Camera Rune.